# MVC, Strongly Typed Views and Entity Framework dilemma

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've read quite a few Q & As relating to logic in views within an MVC architecture and in most cases I agree that business logic shouldn't live in a view. However having said this, I constantly question my approach when using Microsoft's MVC Framework in conjunction with the Entity Framework because of the ease of accessibility to foreign key relationships a single entity can give me which ultimately results in me performing Linq to Entities queries inline within a View.

For example:

If I have the following two entities:

Product ([PK]ProductId, Title, Amount)

Image ([PK]ImageId, [FK]ProductId, ImageTitle, DisplayOrder)

Assuming I have a strongly typed Product view and I want to display the primary image (lowest display order) then I could do something like this in the view:

```
@{
     Image image = (from l in Model.Image
                    orderby l.DisplayOrder
                    select l).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This is a simple example for demonstration purposes, but surely this begins to bend the rules in relation to MVC architecture, but on the other hand doing this in the Controller and then (heaven forbid) jamming it into the ViewBag or ViewData would surely be just as much of a crime and become painful to manage for more than a few different related classes.

I used to create custom classes for complex Models, but it's time-consuming and ugly and I no longer see the point as the Entity Framework makes it quick and easy to define the View to be the primary Model (in this case a Product) and then easily retrieve all the peripheral components of the product using Linq queries.

I'd be interested to know how other people handle this type of scenario.

EDIT:

I also quite often do things like:

```
@foreach(Image i in Model.Image.OrderBy(e => e.DisplayOrder).ToList())
{
   <img ... />
}
```

Comment: Haven't you run into some problems with model binding? When you're doing GET and then POST back your stuff with possible user edits, you need to have all fields bound, else you may loose some data when you persist it to database. Updated my answer also.

Comment: @Bartosz - Nope, I very very occasionally (twice in 5 large projects) have to use a bind exclusion but on the most part I can go gangbusters with Display & Editor Templates and with things like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image.OrderBy(e => e.DisplayOrder)) and it works brilliantly for POSTing to the controller

Comment: What about validation? With Viewmodels you could use MVC validation annotations, wheras with EF classes, you would be polluting them with non-EF stuff.

Comment: Yeah that works like a charm (unobtrusive) in Editor Templates, but you make a good point here, something else I've always pushed back on, I define validation using partial classes against the Entity, so it's tightly coupled. My reasoning is; if I have an email field and it's not nullable in the DB then I don't see the point in defining the validation rules for every view as the rule is just going to be duplicated and what if I change my DB to allow nulls, I have to go and change it 5 different places. Very occasionally I'll create a custom model to override my tight coupling but 99% its fine.

Comment: Back to the point with model binding. Don't you fear you're exposing too much info to end-user? If your models needs to be POST back as a whole, there's gonna be lots of info in your html...

Comment: The only fields in the View are those I choose to display (or stored in hidden fields), it just boils down to HTML in the end, ultimately I have to define which fields are present in the view using things like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductTitle)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going the 'custom classes for Models' way, and I agree it's time consuming and mundane, hence tools like http://automapper.codeplex.com/ have been created, to accompany you with this task.

Overall, I'm having similar feelings to yours. Reading some stuff saying it's good to have your domain model unrelated to your storage, then different class for your view model than the domain model, and then seeing that libraries actually seem to 'promote' the easy way (data annotations over your domain classes seem to be simplier than EF fluent interface etc etc).

At least we've got the choice I guess!

**Model binding** There is also issue that when you want to POST back the model data and store it in the database, you need to be careful and make sure MVC model binders bind all fields correctly. Else you may loose some data. With custom models for views, it might be simplier.

**Validation**
MVC gives you a way to validate using attributes, when you use viewmodels, you can freely pollute it with such annotations, because it's view specific (and validation should be view/controller action specific as well). When you use EF classes, you would be polluting those classes with unrelated (and possibly conflicting) logic.

Comment: I hate the idea of using third party products to perform mappings and custom class building when it's already at my fingertips in the Entity Framework but thanks for your feedback :-) - I agree with your second point too, as I said in my post, I don't believe the bulk of the business logic should touch the view, but I kind of feel like there is a quasi display logic that should live in the view when you're using the EF